# how to divided one column into two column in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I m working with SQL and I want to divide one column into two-column in SQL

Image:

**Database Diagram:**

[image]

**Table and query**

[image]

In my program, **two users share the same account and I want to display what they do for this account**.

I have one-field transaction management and divided into two-column credit and debit :

what my logic

//if a user has> 0 means credit and user have < 0 then debit and display the total balance

```
Select transactionid,
      transactiondate,
      case WHEN transactionamount > 0 Then 'Credit' As Credit,
      case WHEN transactionamount < 0 Then 'Debit' As Debit,
      totalbalance,
      userid
      from transactions where userid = 1
```

for ex what I want to:

where userid = 1

```
transactionid  credit debit  totalbalance   userid
2              5000   -        5000          1
5               -     -1500    3500          1
```

where userid = 2

```
transactionid   credit   debit  totalbalance   userid
3                -      -1000    4000            2
4                2000     -      6000            2
```

currently, give an error **Incorrect syntax near As**

How to solve this problem? help

Comment: Your case expression is missing an `end`

Comment: @HoneyBadger did not solve the issue ```Then END 'Credit' As Credit```

Comment: Please research how to use `case` properly. First do your own research, then ask a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the amounts in different columns depending wether they are positive or negative. You can use two `case` expressions for this:

```
select 
    transactionid,
    case when transactionamount >= 0 then transactionamount end credit,
    case when transactionamount <  0 then transactionamount end debit,
    totalbalance,
    userid
from transactions
where userid = ?
order by transactionid
```

Note that this produces `null` when a transaction does not fall in the right bucket rather than `'-'` (which is a string, and would require additional manipulations).

If you were running MySQL (or another database that, unlike SQL Server, supports `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()`):

```
select 
    transactionid,
    greatest(transactionamount, 0) credit,
    least(transactionamount, 0) debit,
    totalbalance,
    userid
from transactions
where userid = ?
order by transactionid
```

Comment: this is if a condition or else condition can u tell me which condition is run ```then transactionamount end credit``` either if condition run either else condition run

Comment: @rajubhai: since there is no `else`, this produces `null` when the condition is not met.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select
  transactionid,
  transactiondate,
  case WHEN transactionamount > 0 Then 'Credit' end As Credit,
  case WHEN transactionamount < 0 Then 'Debit' end As Debit,
  totalbalance,
  userid
from transactions where userid = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying with the wrong syntax. Here are the details of [CASE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
 in SQL Server.

Syntax

Simple CASE expression:

```
CASE input_expression   
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ]   
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ]   
END   
Searched CASE expression:  
CASE  
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ]   
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ]   
END
```

For your query.

```
SELECT transactionid
    ,transactiondate
    ,CASE 
        WHEN ISNULL(transactionamount, 0) > 0
            THEN 'Credit'
        END AS Credit
    ,CASE 
        WHEN ISNULL(transactionamount, 0) < 0
            THEN 'Debit'
        END AS Debit
    ,totalbalance
    ,userid
FROM transactions
WHERE userid = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to show the strings 'Credit' or 'Debit', but rather show the transaction amounts in the two columns "credit" and "debit". Moreover, you are missing the keyword `END` with the `CASE` expression.

```
select
  transactionid,
  transactiondate,
  case when transactionamount > 0 then transactionamount end as credit,
  case when transactionamount < 0 then transactionamount end as debit,
  totalbalance,
  userid
from transactions
where userid = 1
order by transactiondate;
```